# Legal status of "help provided for harm"

Tags: california, san-francisco

If someone harmed you (eg accidentally killed your son or dog or right arm) and gave you $x because you are having asked for it **and** you are poor.

In the eyes of law what is the status of that property transfer? And is there a difference if it is in writing  (with signatures etc)?

( Should it be a contract, what on earth is their consideration?<sup>other than that they feel better</sup> )

Answer (score 3):

#### Settlement

Normally, when a defendant or potential defendant pays money to an injured party, with the intention that the payment satisfy any potential legal liability for the payor's conduct, the payor will have the injured party enter into a contract called a "[settlement agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Settlement_(litigation))" (also called a "release," or a "waiver of liability"). This is a contract wherein, in exchange for the money, the injured party promises never to sue the payor for some specific conduct.

#### Gift

You also seem to be asking about how the law would treat a transfer of money from A to B, when:

- B is poor;
- B has asked for money from A; and
- A has harmed B.

Nothing prevents A from gifting money to B in this circumstance. But for this to be a gift, a court would look to the [well-established criteria for a gift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_(law)):

1. donative intent;
2. acceptance by the donee; and
3. delivery.

A and B do not need to enter a contract for a gift to be effective.

Comment: The injured party **does not** make  such a representation. ( besides $x is way too low for you could sue and potentially win millions or a sum far beyond $x)

Comment: @Pacerier the law does not care what amount you accept to enter a contract (which is what a settlement agreement is), so Luong as there is consideration,, $1 is enough.

Comment: @DaleM Not true, if consideration is far too low, a judge may find the contract unconscionable.

Comment: @user71659 highly unlikely. There are plenty of contracts where the consideration is obviously insignificant and both parties know this. Such contracts, called peppercorn contracts, are perfectly valid. Unconscionably requires more than adequate compensation, there must have been a knowing and deliberate effort by one party to take advantage of a particular vulnerability in the other. Entering a contract for a too low a price just because you screwed up does not allow you to play the “unconscionable” card.

Comment: @DaleM Again, untrue. You are getting two different concepts confused. While a peppercorn is valid consideration, unconscionability is a different standard. Grossly inadequate compensation is strong evidence of unconscionability, fraud or duress. Read "Jeffrey C. Fort, Understanding Unconscionability: Defining the Principle, 9 Loy. U. Chi. L. J. 765 (1978)."